# Text background stands out when printing. What you see on screen is not what you get from the printer

Tags: color, print-design, pdf, svg

Please can you advise me ? I made posters in Inkscape, being equations on coloured backgrounds. I blurred the equations because I think it looks "artistic" :) I then saved the Inkscape .svg files to pdf files, and had a copy shop print them out. On printing, the text has acquired a rectangular background of a colour which contrasts with the rest of the page:

[image]

How can I avoid this ? On screen there was no such rectangle.

EDIT

Opening the svg in internet explorer, it looks fine, i.e. there is no contrasting rectangle.

The Inkscape settings I used to save as pdf are:
Restrict to PDF version 1.5.
Convert text to paths: UNCHECKED
PDF and Latex: Omit text in pdf, and create LaTeX file: unchecked.
Rasterize Filter effects: checked. (Otherwise the text will not be blurred in the pdf file.)
Resolution for rasterization: 300 dpi
Output page size: Use document's page size
Bleed / margin (mm)  0.0

I don't know how to work with Layers.

The svg code is here:

[the code of the svg file](http://pastebin.com/2CgGjcEA)

Answer (score 1):

My answer probably doesn't help with your issue from the program itself but you could now just print the SVG from the jsfiddle link.

You have to turn the fill to 0

Change

```
<rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#63058f;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.08000001;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect4291"
     width="663.66199"
     height="917.18317"
     x="-31.549295"
     y="-36.983276" />
```

to

```
<rect
     style="opacity:1;fill:#fffffff;fill-opacity:0;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.08000001;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect4291"
     width="663.66199"
     height="917.18317"
     x="-31.549295"
     y="-36.983276" />
```

See example https://jsfiddle.net/5qs1sffh/

**This will take out the background color of the graphic** and you are going to be left with the shade of blue or whatever you make the background color. I just removed the color from your SVG graphic.

An alternative to this is to make the background the same color as the background color in the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

When you blur a vector it is transformed or interpreted as a bitmap (raster) image.

Inside the Inkscape it is still a vector, but the pdf can not interpret that, becouse it is not on the pdf language, so it is converted to a bitmap.

So you now have a bitmap over your other elements. Probably that image is rgb and your background is defined as cmyk.

You need to flatten the image. This is: convert all thoose big zones of color, transparencies, blurred objects to one single bitmap, and you can have sharp elements as vectors, normally texts.

In the case of your image, probably leave the QR codes in vectors if you have them as such.

**P.S.** I always have 2 copies of thoose kinds of files.

1) My working file. Whith all my effects.

2) A copy which is the one I modify and flaten.